QT6 Scrollable and zoomable image viewer
I'm trying to port an MCF/C++ widget to QT6.
The widget has a custom paint function to draw the part of the image that's visible to the user.
Practically all examples showed a QLabel as a child for a ScrollArea which doesn't let me override the Widgets (QLabel) paint event.
Several design options came to mind with QT6:

Inherit from QWidget, have QScrollArea and some child widget to fill it (QWidget?).
Inherit from QScrollArea and have some child widget to fill it (QWidget?).
Inherit from QWidget, have QScrollbars as members and override paintEvent for the class

My widget should catch all mouse events so the user can drag/pan the image, zoom in/out, etc.
The drawing/paint callback of the image must be my function as it needs to know, the scroll positions (v/h), zoom level, and the client area to draw on. I don't want to draw massive images only to be cropped by the QScrollArea (e.g. support at least zoom of x256).
Any suggestions on how to design this w/o reimplementing the wheel?

QGraphicsView + QGraphicsPixmapItem?
